How to use the `.is if key` as an optional argument in a macro?
I'm trying to learn \pgfkeys, but I don't quite understand how to use it to create a macro with key=value options.
I created a macro \aiguille that draws a clock with 3 parameters:

#1 optional to pass specific commands like shift={(5,0)} as well as for an is if key
#2 for hours
#3 for minutes
I'm trying to create a boolean key that when true draws the hands as a point and otherwise as a rectangle.
I tried to use Key handler key/.is if=, copying the manual here: Key handler ⟨key⟩/.is if but it doesn't work.


How do I pass an optional argument as a is if key that changes the shape of the clock hands?

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pointe', to
which you pas sed 'false', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
misspelled it. See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.

\documentclass{article}                          
\usepackage{tikz}                              
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   
   
\newif\ifaiguillesenpointe
\aiguillesenpointefalse
\pgfkeys
  {%
    /pointe/.is if=aiguillesenpointe
    ,/pointe=false
  }

\newcommand\aiguille[3][]{% #2 heure #3 minutes
\def\rayon{1.5}
\begin{scope}[#1]
\fill[red!5](0,0)circle(\rayon);
\draw(0,0)circle(\rayon);
\foreach \a [count=\n] in {60,30,...,-270}
    {\draw[thick](\a:\rayon)--(\a:\rayon-.15);
     \foreach \i in {6,12,18,24}\draw[thin](\a-\i:\rayon-.1)--(\a-\i:\rayon);
}
\foreach \a [count=\n] in {60,30,...,-180}{\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\a:1.2){\n};}
\foreach \a [count=\n from 10] in {-210,-240,-270}{\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\a:1.2){\n};}

\ifaiguillesenpointe
% aiguilles en pointe
% petite aiguille
\fill({-#2*30}:2pt)--({90-#2*30-#3.5}:.7)--({-#2*30}:-2pt)arc[start angle=-#2*30,delta angle=180,radius=-2pt];
grande aiguille
\fill(-#3*6:2pt)--({90-#3*6}:1.1)--({-#3*6}:-2pt)arc[start angle=-#3*6,delta angle=180,radius=-2pt];
\else
% aiguilles en rectangle
%petite aiguille 1 h=30°; 1 min= 0.5°; midi = 90°
\draw[line width=2pt](90-#2*30-#3*.5:.7)--(90-#2*30-#3*.5:-.1);
%grande aiguille 0 min = 90°; 1 min = 6°
\draw[line width=2pt](90-#3*6:1)--(90-#3*6:-.15);
%\node[fill=red!5,inner sep=1.5pt] at (0,-1.8){Il est \hms{#2:#3}};
\fi
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\aiguille[pointe=false]{4}{30}%<--- dont work
\aiguille{4}{30}% work

\aiguille[shift={(5,0)}]{7}{10}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Your issue is that you pass your options to scope, but that doesn't have any idea about your option pointe.
You have two options, the one the first version of my answer showed is kept below for posterity. That version installs an .unknown handler to store away the list of options that weren't known and forward them to the scope environment.
Using .search also
The other option you might use is the .search also handler, which this part of the answer presents.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifaiguillesenpointe
\pgfqkeys{/andreC}
  {%
    .is family,
    pointe/.is if=aiguillesenpointe, pointe=false,
    .search also={/tikz}
  }

\newcommand\aiguille[3][]{% #2 heure #3 minutes
  \begingroup
  \def\rayon{1.5}
  \pgfqkeys{/andreC}{#1}
  \begin{scope}
    \fill[red!5](0,0)circle(\rayon);
    \draw(0,0)circle(\rayon);
    \foreach \a [count=\n] in {60,30,...,-270}
    {\draw[thick](\a:\rayon)--(\a:\rayon-.15);
      \foreach \i in {6,12,18,24}\draw[thin](\a-\i:\rayon-.1)--(\a-\i:\rayon);
    }
    \foreach \a [count=\n] in {60,30,...,-180}{\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\a:1.2){\n};}
    \foreach \a [count=\n from 10] in {-210,-240,-270}{\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\a:1.2){\n};}

    \ifaiguillesenpointe
      % aiguilles en pointe
      % petite aiguille
      \fill({-#2*30}:2pt)--({90-#2*30-#3.5}:.7)--({-#2*30}:-2pt)arc[start angle=-#2*30,delta angle=180,radius=-2pt];
      % grande aiguille
      \fill(-#3*6:2pt)--({90-#3*6}:1.1)--({-#3*6}:-2pt)arc[start angle=-#3*6,delta angle=180,radius=-2pt];
    \else
      % aiguilles en rectangle
      %petite aiguille 1 h=30°; 1 min= 0.5°; midi = 90°
      \draw[line width=2pt](90-#2*30-#3*.5:.7)--(90-#2*30-#3*.5:-.1);
      %grande aiguille 0 min = 90°; 1 min = 6°
      \draw[line width=2pt](90-#3*6:1)--(90-#3*6:-.15);
      %\node[fill=red!5,inner sep=1.5pt] at (0,-1.8){Il est \hms{#2:#3}};
    \fi
  \end{scope}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\aiguille[pointe=true]{4}{30}% work

\aiguille[shift={(5,0)}]{7}{10}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Using .unknown and manually forwarding
The following changes this to instead set all options as part of the path /andreC, and therein store every unknown key in a list that's then forwarded to scope instead.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifaiguillesenpointe
\let\aiguilleUnknown\empty
\pgfkeys
  {%
    /andreC/.cd,
    pointe/.is if=aiguillesenpointe, pointe=false,
    .unknown/.code=
      \edef\aiguilleUnknown
        {%
          \unexpanded\expandafter{\aiguilleUnknown},%
          \unexpanded\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentname={#1}}%
        }
  }

\newcommand\aiguille[3][]{% #2 heure #3 minutes
  \begingroup
  \def\rayon{1.5}
  \pgfkeys{/andreC/.cd,#1}
  \expanded{\noexpand\begin{scope}[\unexpanded\expandafter{\aiguilleUnknown}]}
    \fill[red!5](0,0)circle(\rayon);
    \draw(0,0)circle(\rayon);
    \foreach \a [count=\n] in {60,30,...,-270}
    {\draw[thick](\a:\rayon)--(\a:\rayon-.15);
      \foreach \i in {6,12,18,24}\draw[thin](\a-\i:\rayon-.1)--(\a-\i:\rayon);
    }
    \foreach \a [count=\n] in {60,30,...,-180}{\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\a:1.2){\n};}
    \foreach \a [count=\n from 10] in {-210,-240,-270}{\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\a:1.2){\n};}

    \ifaiguillesenpointe
      % aiguilles en pointe
      % petite aiguille
      \fill({-#2*30}:2pt)--({90-#2*30-#3.5}:.7)--({-#2*30}:-2pt)arc[start angle=-#2*30,delta angle=180,radius=-2pt];
      % grande aiguille
      \fill(-#3*6:2pt)--({90-#3*6}:1.1)--({-#3*6}:-2pt)arc[start angle=-#3*6,delta angle=180,radius=-2pt];
    \else
      % aiguilles en rectangle
      %petite aiguille 1 h=30°; 1 min= 0.5°; midi = 90°
      \draw[line width=2pt](90-#2*30-#3*.5:.7)--(90-#2*30-#3*.5:-.1);
      %grande aiguille 0 min = 90°; 1 min = 6°
      \draw[line width=2pt](90-#3*6:1)--(90-#3*6:-.15);
      %\node[fill=red!5,inner sep=1.5pt] at (0,-1.8){Il est \hms{#2:#3}};
    \fi
  \end{scope}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\aiguille[pointe=true]{4}{30}% work

\aiguille[shift={(5,0)}]{7}{10}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Result of both code blocks:


The first version requires a good understanding of the usage of the primitives \expanded \noexpand \unexpanded \expandafter. Do you have a manual (simple if possible) to recommend for this?

@AndréC I'm afraid not, no. \noexpand is part of Knuthian TeX. It just means the next token shouldn't expand. Same for \expandafter, which just means expand the second next token before the immediate next token is considered. \unexpanded is part of e-TeX and is similar to \noexpand, but instead of only applying to a single token it takes a balanced text as argument and applies to the entire argument. \expanded is a recent addition, originally from LuaTeX, nowadays in e-TeX. It's taking a balanced text and expands it as Knuthian TeX would do inside a \message.

@AndréC Since both \unexpanded and \expanded read what TeX calls a balanced text they expand everything they encounter until they find an opening brace. For that reason \unexpanded\expandafter{#1} expands the first token of #1 once and then \unexpanded finds its opening brace and protects the result of that from further expanding.

@AndréC if these comments aren't enough for you to understand these primitives you might want to search the site, there should be plenty of material explaining their details.

Thank you very much. The advantage of the second version is that it does the same job while avoiding TeX primitives and additional macros.

In your second solution, you write \begin{scope} instead of \begin{scope}[#1]. How come the optional parameter like shift={(5,0)} are still passed to the scope environment?

@AndréC Because it's parsed as a TikZ key. Same would happen if you used \tikzset{shift={(5,0)}}\begin{scope}...\end{scope}.

Thanks for your explanation. Another question if you don't mind: the handler .search also={/tikz} finds all the keys in the path \tikzand executes them. This therefore executes the key pointe if it exists as well as the other options like shift={(5,0)}. Did I understand correctly?

@AndréC no, only if pointe doesn't exist in the currently searched path (/andreC in my code).
